# Ember-CLI Not Resolving Ember 2.0

Tags: ember.js, bower, ember-cli

I've created a brand new project using ember-cli v1.13.8.

I created a new project and then adjusted the bower.json file for Ember 2.0 (it is currently configured for Ember 1.13.8). I receive the following error after running `bower install ember@2.0.0`

```
bower ember-data#2.0.0          cached https://github.com/components/ember-data.git#2.0.0
bower ember-data#2.0.0        validate 2.0.0 against https://github.com/components/ember-data.git#2.0.0
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package ember@2.0.0 not found
```

I also tried `bower install ember#2.0.0` and received this error (partial message posted here):

```
bower ember#2.0.0              extract archive.tar.gz
bower ember#2.0.0              extract archive.tar.gz
bower ember#2.0.0         invalid-meta ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower. json
bower ember#2.0.0             resolved https://github.com/components/ember.git#2 .0.0
bower ember#2.0.0         invalid-meta ember is missing "ignore" entry in bower. json
bower ember#2.0.0             resolved https://github.com/components/ember.git#2 .0.0
bower                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for ember
```

Any idea what's wrong with my configuration?  It's disappointing this is broken right out of the box.

Andrew

Here are my config files....

package.xml

```
   {
      "name": "ars-app",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "description": "Small description for ars-app goes here",
      "private": true,
      "directories": {
        "doc": "doc",
        "test": "tests"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "build": "ember build",
        "start": "ember server",
        "test": "ember test"
      },
      "repository": "",
      "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.10.0"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "MIT",
      "devDependencies": {
        "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.1.2",
        "ember-cli": "1.13.8",
        "ember-cli-app-version": "0.5.0",
        "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.3",
        "ember-cli-content-security-policy": "0.4.0",
        "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.0.1",
        "ember-cli-htmlbars": "0.7.9",
        "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.2.0",
        "ember-cli-ic-ajax": "0.2.1",
        "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.3.1",
        "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.0.0",
        "ember-cli-release": "0.2.3",
        "ember-cli-sri": "^1.0.3",
        "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
        "ember-data": "2.0.0",
        "ember-disable-proxy-controllers": "^1.0.0",
        "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.3"
      }
    }
```

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "ars-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.0.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.4",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.9",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18",
    "jquery": "^1.11.3",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.1",
    "qunit": "~1.18.0"
  }
}
```

Here are the results of running `bower info ember`

```
$ bower info ember
bower ember#*                   cached https://github.com/components/ember.git#2.0.1
bower ember#*                 validate 2.0.1 against https://github.com/components/ember.git#*

{
  name: 'ember',
  version: '2.0.1',
  main: [
    './ember.debug.js',
    './ember-template-compiler.js'
  ],
  dependencies: {
    jquery: '>= 1.7.0 < 2.2.0'
  },
  homepage: 'https://github.com/components/ember'
}

Available versions:
  - 2.1.0-beta.2
  - 2.1.0-beta.1
  - 2.0.1
  - 2.0.0
  - 2.0.0-beta.5
  - 2.0.0-beta.4
  - 2.0.0-beta.3
  - 2.0.0-beta.2
  - 2.0.0-beta.1
  - 1.13.9
  - 1.13.8
  - 1.13.7
  - 1.13.6
  - 1.13.5
  - 1.13.4
  - 1.13.3
  - 1.13.2
  - 1.13.1
  - 1.13.0
  - 1.13.0-beta.2
  - 1.13.0-beta.1
  - 1.12.1
  - 1.12.0
  - 1.12.0-beta.3
  - 1.12.0-beta.2
  - 1.12.0-beta.1
  - 1.11.3
  - 1.11.2
  - 1.11.1
  - 1.11.0
  - 1.11.0-beta.5
  - 1.11.0-beta.4
  - 1.11.0-beta.3
  - 1.11.0-beta.2
  - 1.11.0-beta.1
  - 1.10.1
  - 1.10.0
  - 1.10.0-beta.4
  - 1.10.0-beta.3
  - 1.10.0-beta.2
  - 1.10.0-beta.1
  - 1.9.1
  - 1.9.0
  - 1.9.0-beta.4
  - 1.9.0-beta.3
  - 1.9.0-beta.1
  - 1.8.1
  - 1.8.0
  - 1.8.0-beta.5
  - 1.8.0-beta.4
  - 1.8.0-beta.3
  - 1.8.0-beta.2
  - 1.8.0-beta.1
  - 1.7.1
  - 1.7.0
  - 1.7.0-beta.5
  - 1.7.0-beta.4
  - 1.7.0-beta.3
  - 1.7.0-beta.2
  - 1.7.0-beta.1
  - 1.6.1
  - 1.6.0
  - 1.6.0-beta.5
  - 1.6.0-beta.4
  - 1.6.0-beta.3
  - 1.6.0-beta.2
  - 1.6.0-beta.1
  - 1.5.1
  - 1.5.0
  - 1.5.0-beta.4
  - 1.5.0-beta.3
  - 1.5.0-beta.2
  - 1.5.0-beta.1
  - 1.4.0
  - 1.4.0-beta.6
  - 1.4.0-beta.5
  - 1.4.0-beta.4
  - 1.4.0-beta.3
  - 1.4.0-beta.2
  - 1.4.0-beta.1
  - 1.3.2
  - 1.3.1
  - 1.3.0
  - 1.3.0-beta.4
  - 1.3.0-beta.3
  - 1.3.0-beta.2
  - 1.3.0-beta.1
  - 1.2.2
  - 1.2.1
  - 1.2.0
  - 1.2.0-beta.4
  - 1.2.0-beta.3
  - 1.2.0-beta.2
  - 1.2.0-beta.1
  - 1.1.3
  - 1.1.2
  - 1.1.1
  - 1.1.0
  - 1.1.0-beta.4
  - 1.1.0-beta.2
  - 1.1.0-beta.1
  - 1.0.1
  - 1.0.0
  - 1.0.0-rc.8
  - 1.0.0-rc.7
  - 1.0.0-rc.6.1
  - 1.0.0-rc.6
  - 1.0.0-rc.5
  - 1.0.0-rc.4
  - 1.0.0-rc.3
  - 1.0.0-rc.2
  - 1.0.0-rc.1
  - 1.0.0-pre.4
  - 1.0.0-pre.2
  - 1.0.0-pre
```

Update:  After removing some of the entries to see if there was a dependency conflict between entries, I found something interesting.  If I remove just this single entry `"ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5"`, then bower is able to successfully install ember#2.0.0.  Does anyone know of an issue with the ember-load-initializer dependency definition?  It appears to be part of ember-cli which is still on version 1.13.8 (as of today).

Comment: will you do `bower info ember` at the command line?

Comment: That error is a little weird too, it makes it look like their is a hidden space in your version.

Comment: Did you also try just doing a `bower install`, generally it will help resolve when it's confused?

Comment: I've added the results of running 'bower info ember'

Comment: Btw.. if I remove all of the other bower depedencies from the bower.json file and then run 'bower install ember#2.0.0', it DOES install the dependency succesfully. This makes me think theres are conflict between one of the dependencies (ie. one dependency only accepts Ember version less than 2.0)

Comment: Adding to my previous comment...  "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.5", seems to be the problem.  If I remove that from my bower.json file and then run 'bower install ember#2.0.0' it works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updating this dependency to version 0.1.6 (From 0.1.5) in my bower.json file solved the problem.  The newer version supports Ember 2.0.

```
"ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.6"
```

Here's my full (working) bower file:

```
{
  "name": "ars-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "2.0.1",
    "ember-cli-shims": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.4",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "ember-cli-test-loader#0.1.3",
    "ember-data": "2.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.6",
    "ember-qunit": "0.4.9",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "0.0.7",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18", 
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.1",
    "qunit": "~1.18.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your entire Bower file, I had to also update ember-cli-shims from 0.0.3 to 0.0.4, in case anyone else is having a similar issue: `"ember-cli-shims:": "ember-cli/ember-cli-shims#0.0.4"`.

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in bower command. To specify a version use `#`:

```
bower install ember#2.0.0
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and received an error.  I've updated my original post with the full error message.